# Angular material inclusion cause : NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material, rider

I'm trying to add material components to my project. As soon as I import, for example, MatToolbarModule, every page hang with NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection [...].

I've tried it with a new project that was working without it.

I'm running angular 15 with node 18.04. I'm also using jetbrains rider(it's a dotnet backend)

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you are new to angular, remember to update and install @angular/material  via "ng add" before using it...